# Drawable reset when scroll in recyclerview

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

today i need help from you!
I have a recyclerview with some data(get from json), with adapter.

I have some button(with id) with a drawable left, and onclick on the button i execute this for the clicked button :

```
Drawable image = ContextCompat.getDrawable(context, R.drawable.active);
image.setBounds(0, 0, 70, 70);
Button.setCompoundDrawables(image, null, null, null);
```

I Change the drawable with a new drawable.

My question is now.

When i click on some button in the list, and i scroll, the button return to default drawable... WHY?

Thanks every one for help!

Resolve with movies.add(new Costructor("","","","","","",""));

Comment: u need to maintain which button is clicked in to a hash map. use it to again show it in the list.

Comment: how make this?:...

Comment: I remind you that the data is saved on a server, and when I took the code works. For example I click on the button, modify the drawable, and sending the change request to the server (successfully) but if I  scroll disappears the new drawable and if i refresh adapter with new data i get success!   this happened when i already load adapter and i modifiy drawable, and if i scroll disappear the new drawable!

Answer (score 0):

When you scroll `RecyclerView` then all data reset with `Adapter's` data.
When you click and change `Drawable` with `R.drawable.active`, It will change only in screen for temporary.
Please update `Adapter's` data.